# Не отображаются сгенирированные свг фигуры

Tags: javascript, svg

Верхняя фигура, вне поля (сразу после .container), изначально есть в разметке. Точно такие же добавляются в разметку скриптом и в разметке они появляются, но изображения нет. В чём дело?

https://github.com/AnatolySokolov/GeekbrainsJS1/pull/2/commits/da4239ae116ef897f61a4afab95c67aa4e58a9b6

```
let el = document.createElement(tagName);
if (className) {
  if (Array.isArray(className)) {
    className.forEach(function (name) {
      el.classList.add(name);
    });
  } else {
    el.classList.add(className);
  }
}
if (content) {
  el.textContent = content;
}
```

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Неймспейса не хватает

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/760648/190728

Comment: Когда задавал вопрос, смотрел подобные вопросы. Видел про namespace, но не разобрался что это и как работает.
Вот, здесь ещё нашёл подробное объяснение.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319537/html-5-inline-svg-and-namespace-awareness-for-svg-dom
В структуре svg > use, к use тоже надо указывать namespace.
Вопрос решён.
Спасибо за ответы Qwertiy, Alexey Ten.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> let el = document.createElement(tagName);
> ```

```
let el = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", tagName);
```